# Elastic Search Index definition gets overridden

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am trying to create an elastic search index using the following Java code

```
    public class MappingCreator {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MappingCreator.class.getName());

    final static String indexName =  "indxyz";

    final static String typeName = "indtype";

    final static String mappingFileName = "customMapping.json";

    final static String clusterName = "elasticsearch";

    final static String hostName = "localhost";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        MappingCreator mapCreator = new MappingCreator();

        Client myESclient = getClient();

        IndicesExistsResponse res = myESclient.admin().indices().prepareExists(indexName).execute().actionGet();

        if (res.isExists()) {

            log.warn("Index "+indexName +" already exists. Will be deleted");

            final DeleteIndexRequestBuilder deleteIndexBuilder = myESclient.admin().indices().prepareDelete(indexName);

            deleteIndexBuilder.execute().actionGet();
        }

        final CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexBuilder = myESclient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexName)
                .addMapping(typeName, mapCreator.getIndexFieldMapping());

        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = createIndexBuilder.execute().actionGet();

        log.debug("Created mapping "+createIndexResponse.toString());

        myESclient.close();

    }

    private String getIndexFieldMapping() throws IOException {

        return IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(mappingFileName));
    }

    private static Client getClient() {

        TransportClient transportClient = null;

        try
        {
            Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();

            transportClient = new TransportClient(settings);

            transportClient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostName, 9300));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error in MappingCreator creating Elastic Search Client\n"
                    + "Message "+e.getMessage()+"\n"
                            + "StackTrace "+e.getStackTrace()
                    );
        }

        return (Client) transportClient;

    }

}
```

customMapping.json looks like this

```
 {

                "properties": {

                   "popkDate": {

                      "type":"date",
                      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSZ"
                   },

                   "popk": {
                      "type": "string"
                   }
                }
    }
```

now, after creating the mapping, if i run the following in the elasticsearch marvel plugin

```
get indxyz/
```

i get

```
 {
   "indxyz": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "indtype": {
            "properties": {
               "popkDate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSZ"
               },
               "popk": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
       }
```

which is accurate.

now when i try to ingest this data

```
  {
        "popkDate":"2001-01-01T235959.00-0400",
        "popk":"cuinbcwenvubn"
    }
```

for some reason, the popkDate field is indexed as String, instead of Date. Now, if i again look at

```
get indxyz/
```

this time i get,

```
{
       "indxyz": {
          "aliases": {},
          "mappings": {
             "indtype": {
                "properties": {
                   "popkDate": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss.SSZ"
                   },
                   "popk": {
                      "type": "string"
                   }
                }
             },

           "indtype": {
                "properties": {
                   "popkDate": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                   "popk": {
                      "type": "string"
                   }
                }
             }
           }
```

why was this duplicate mapping created ? for the same type ? Note that if i create the mapping  without the JAVA api, i.e. through curl commands, then this behavior is not observed and the popkDate field is indexed as expected. Why would this be ?

Please advise.

Comment: Did you obfuscate the output in any way? The mapping output that you provided is simply not possible. It's not even a valid JSON (it's missing closing '}' for example). Which command are you using to ingest your data?

Comment: i am ingesting using the EsBolt in a storm topology. the data resides in a Kafka queue.i create a topology that has a KafkaSpout to relay the data to the ESBolt. but before that i execute my MappingCreator code to create the mapping

Comment: i left out the bottom part of the mapping output, which has all the metadata like settings and shards. probably i missed out on the closing } doing that

Comment: And the type is called `indtype` in both cases in real life?

Comment: I just don't see how this output is even possible considering that it is generated from a [map](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/indices/get/RestGetIndicesAction.java#L135) Which version of elasticsearch is it?

Comment: yes, thats the strange part ! when i first create the mapping, i define the type name as indtype. then, when the duplicate mapping is created, its created with the same type !

Comment: Could you run `curl localhost:9200/indxyz > index.txt` without using sense or any other tools and post index.txt somewhere as is without touching it?